# Document Stored in File System Text Searching and Filtering required in ASP .Net Application

Tags: asp.net, indexing, search-engine

We are building a jobsite application in which we will store resumes of all the candidates, which is planned to store on file system.

Now We need to search inside that file and provide the result to the user, we need to provide that what is the best solution to implement text searching.

I have just tried to identify it and got some reference like IFilter (API or interface) and Lucene.Net (open source), but not sure that is it a right solution.

In initial phase it is expected to be around 50,000 resumes and it should be scalable enough if number increases.

I just want some case study or some analysis or your suggestions that which is the best method to handle this requirement (Technology ASP .Net)

Thanks

Comment: I would like you to use sharepoint for this

Comment: wss 3.0 does not provide content search facility (MOSS is out of scope due to prizing) and in any case we have developed our site in asp .net and want a tool which we can integrate with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Search Server](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/default.aspx). There is a free version, so you can try it before buy it (or never buy, if it meets your requirements).

If, later, you do want to integrate that documents into a Sharepoint portal, Enterprise Search can also integrate with it.

Comment: is it possible to integrate search server express with our custom application. if yes can you provide any link for the same.

Comment: You can to create a custom connector through an API; Take a look in these production-ready connectors: http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-connectors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use the `FILESTREAM` feature in SQL Server 2008, combined with database-level full text index / search.

That would allow you to keep the files in the filesystem, while also providing transactional integrity and search.

SQL Express supports `FILESTREAM`, and the 4GB size limit doesn't apply for the files (although it does apply to the size of a full text index).

Answer (score 0):

This might be naive since I'm unfamiliar with off-the-shelf search products but if nothing pre-build fit the bill I would build a simple service that crawls and indexes (or several instances to crawl different directories to increase speed) and updates a database. If the files were accessed regularly you could build a layer of isolation to prevent collisions.

Rodney